# One-to-many relationship with a variable table

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent, relationships

So, I have a TV Show's website, and I currently have the following tables structure (only listing the relevant columns):

```
Table 1 - TV Shows
id

Table 2 - Episodes
id

Table 3 - Comments 
target
value
```

Both TV Shows and Episodes can have comments, so the "target" column specifies if it is a "TV Show" or a "Episode" comment, and the "value" column specifies its ID.

I already thought of merging both columns and using "x_ID" ("tvshow_id" or "episode_id", like: "tvshow_45" or "episode_9458").

But what I really want to know is: what is the best way to do this? With both ways I described, I can't use foreign keys (I don't know the benefit of this, but I guess it's good). And another problem is to use Laravel's Eloquent feature...

I could just create two comments tables, but I don't know if it's the only or best way...

Can someone help me manage this?

Thank you in advance.

Gabe.

Comment: To fully answer this question, one would need to understand the access patterns you will be using to get at this data.  For example will you always be querying show information along with episode information? Will you need to search comments directly and find the shows/episodes they are related to? and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way it works in laravel, you use `commentable_*` columns:

```
id, commentable_id, commentable_type, value
```

Then you use [a polymorphic relationship](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#polymorphic-relations), so that Eloquent handles it all for you.

---

If you're using migrations, laravel can generate those columns for you:

```php
Schema::create('comments', function($table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->morphs('commentable');
    $table->string('value');
});
```

It'll even automatically create a composite index for you!

Comment: Exactly what I needed! I feel dumb now to have missed it on the documentation, haha. Thank you very much!